# Kusto ingest inline with boolean value

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In a kusto database I have the following table:

```
.create-merge table Records (Source:string, Destinitation:string, IsPrimary:bool, MigratedOn:datetime, Count:int)
```

I'm trying to ingest data into this table using the following command:

```
.ingest inline into table Records <|
src1, dst1, 1, 2023-04-24, 2041
```

But the boolean value isn't being ingested properly, remaining empty.

```
Source  Destinitation   IsPrimary   MigratedOn                  Count
src1    dst1                        2023-04-24 00:00:00.0000000 2041
```

What's the correct way to ingest a boolean colunn?

Better yet, I created json ingestion mapping. How can I use it to ingest from an string json? Meaning to ingest a record represented in json string, not using some uri/url ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data provided to the `inline` ingest command in CSV format shouldn't included excessive whitespaces.

i.e., you should run either of the following instead (the 2nd uses `true` instead of `1`, for improved readability, but the results are identical)

```
.ingest inline into table Records <|
src1,dst1,1,2023-04-24,2041
```

```
.ingest inline into table Records <|
src1,dst1,true,2023-04-24,2041
```